# How do i write a new line to a file every time something is put into a file

Tags: java, file

Hello so today ive been working with txt docs and writing files so i currently have this code

```
try {
                    File file = new File("./Data/Email/Subscribed.txt");
                    if (!file.exists()) {
                        file.createNewFile();
                    }
                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);


                        bw.write(player.playerEmail + ",");


                    bw.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

So my question is how do i make it so every time something is written to the file it writes to the next line down

Comment: Use [`bw.newLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine()).

Comment: I know but it only does it once i need it to do it eveytime someone inputs information that will go into the file

Comment: So do it after each call to `write`.

Comment: How do you detect when someone inputs information?

Comment: player.playerEmail  <-------- this detects the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the `BufferedWriter` in a `PrintWriter` and replace the `write()` calls with `println()`.

Now, every call inserts text on a new line.